# Parametrization of a Closed Section of a Sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to verify Divergence theorem for a specific vector field through the part of a sphere in the first octant.  I've done the volume integral, I'm just having trouble parametrizing the surface formed by the part of sphere in the first octant plus the parts in the x-, y-, and z-planes (because the surface must be closed for Stokes' theorem).

I can't seem to find one parametrization that encompasses all four parts.  Can I just parametrize each section and add the results of those integrals?  If so, for the spherical part, should it be $$\vec r(\theta, \phi) = R(\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\phi))$$ where $$0 \le \theta \lt \frac\pi 2,\ 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$ or should one of those be $\frac \pi 4$ (I'm not entirely sure why a full sphere is $0 \le \theta \lt \pi,\ 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$ as opposed to both variables being to $2 \pi$)?

Comment: You can and should split them up; there's no need for one parametrization when four will do just as well (and _far_ more easily).

Comment: @Semiclassical OK.  I just wasn't sure if that was allowed.

Comment: We have that $0\leq u\leq\pi$ because that's the Altitude of the Sphere. For us, $v$ covers both sides, therefore, we don't need to extend $u$ to $2\pi$ .